# Pluggability in Talend ESB Mediation

Tags: esb, talend

I am new to Talend ESB. I am using Talend Open Studio 5.6.2.
I want to know about pluggability of Talend. Is it possible to Plug Talend component in Talend mediation Route while its running?
For e.g. Suppose my Talend mediation Route application is running and i want to add another component and use it without restarting Talend Server.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can always redeploy routes without restarting the Talend server. Talend ESB is based on the OSGi server Apache Karaf which allows to hot deploy modules.

You can not directly change routes while they are running but you can create pluggability points by using OSGi services in a route. These services can then be implemented by other modules and can be changed without restarting the route.

Do you have a special scenario in mind that requires this?

Comment: Thanks for reply. For e.g. I have used one HTTP connector to send sms. and now i want to add new HTTP conector for another sms provider.can I do it without redeploy.?

Comment: I think in this case you will have to do a redeploy. Theoretically you could use a ManagedServiceFactory to accept several configs and create one instance for each. I do not think this works with Studio though.

Comment: In Talend Open Studio  user guide, they mentioned "Talend ESB has  modular, pluggable architecture allows it to be easily expanded to suit most enterprise requirements." What does it mean for " pluggable architecture "?

I have referred following link for user guide:
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforESBUserGuide56EN/1.Enterprise+Service+Bus%3A+Concepts+and+Principles

Comment: I think pluggable means that you can install and uninstall your routes as bundles at runtime without restarting the whole TESB runtime server.

Comment: When  i am redeploying .kar file in TESB runtime server  without stopping it then for some time server not responding. i am getting 503 Service unavailable response. My aim is to achieve pluggable functionality means Server should response to all request while redeployment or apply new changes.

Comment: This is not possible in a single server. You can achieve it through http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html . To make this work you need two servers and a proxy in front. You take one server offline in the proxy, update it then reenable. Then you do the same with the second server.